# AngularJS ng-if doesn't show the DIV

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Why my app isn't working properly? It must show one (one at time) of the div on the bottom with the "ng-if" tag..
This is the fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgrha06k/10/)

```
<div class="fix" ng-if="showAdd()">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <span class="fix">Aggiungi un Preferito</span>
  </button>
  <div class="add">
  Aggiungi un Preferito
  </div>
</div>
<div class="edit" ng-if="showEdit()">
Modifica
</div>
```

Comment: you can see it in the fiddle.. this is the code:
  'function showEdit() {
   return $scope.startEdit && !$scope.startAdd;
  }'

Comment: Where are the init values coming from e.g. `$scope.startEdit = startEdit`, where is startEdit defined?

Comment: Your functions don't return any value, which is why you'll always get false.

Comment: It's working but the values are not initialised as per my previous comment - https://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/LvaLvntd/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a mistake in your fiddle. The edit div will show up if you change your `showAdd` and `showEdit` methods to the following:

```
function showAdd() {
    return $scope.addBookmark && !$scope.editBookmark;
}

function showEdit() {
    return $scope.editBookmark && !$scope.addBookmark;
}
```

The add div never gets added because that would be activated by the `startAdd` function, which isn't called anywhere.

Also, please post your javascript code here. That way, if something happens to your fiddle, this question might still be useful to others.

EDIT:

To get your add button to work you need to change this:

```
<div class="fix" ng-if="showAdd()">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <span class="fix">Aggiungi un Preferito</span>
  </button>
  <div class="add">
  Aggiungi un Preferito
  </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="startAdd()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <span class="fix">Aggiungi un Preferito</span>
  </button>
<div class="fix" ng-if="showAdd()">
  <div class="add">
  Aggiungi un Preferito
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works for the edit buttons but it doesn't show the add div in the 'normal' view..

Comment: That's because the add button you have doesn't actually call the `startAdd` function. Also, it's inside an `ng-if` directive, so it's never shown. I'll edit the answer with a solution.

Comment: the showAdd() must be always shown (when showEdit is hidden) not on the button click... how can I fix it? hhmmm

Comment: Just change `$scope.addBookmark = false;` to `$scope.addBookmark = true;` at the top of your controller. That way when your app starts up, the `ng-if` for your add div will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `showEdit()` function.

From your fiddle you have:

```
    function showEdit() {
        return $scope.startEdit && !$scope.startAdd;
    }
```

Where `startEdit` and `startAdd` are defined as:

```
    function startAdd() {
        $scope.addBookmark = true;
        $scope.editBookmark = false;
    }


    function startEdit() {
        $scope.editBookmark = true;
        $scope.addBookmark = false;
    }
```

When your ng-if calls `showEdit()` it will return `$scope.startEdit && !$scope.startAdd;`

However, `$scope.startEdit` and `$scope.startAdd` are functions, so they will be "truthy" (i.e. evaluate to `true` in a boolean expression). Therefore, the boolean expression always evaluates to `false` (and your DIV remains hidden).

See below:

```
$scope.startEdit && !$scope.startAdd;
true && !true
true && false
false
```

It looks like you're missing something conceptually with either calling functions or with evaluating boolean expressions.

If you want to call a JavaScript function, you have to follow the name of the function with parenthesis, just like you did with your `ng-if="showEdit()"` block.

Similarly, if `$scope.showEdit()` is meant to call `startAdd()` and `startEdit()`, you should do something like this:

```
    function showEdit() {
        return $scope.startEdit() && !$scope.startAdd();
    }
```

You'd still have a problem, however, as `startEdit()` and `startAdd()` don't return anything, and would therefore evaluate to `undefined`.

If you edit your `showEdit()` function as described above and have `startEdit()` and `startAdd()` return a boolean expression, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is to always show one or the other, then it is best practice to structure the view as follows:

```
<div class="fix" ng-if="showingAdd">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <span class="fix">Aggiungi un Preferito</span>
  </button>
  <div class="add">
  Aggiungi un Preferito
  </div>
</div>
<div class="edit" ng-if="!showingAdd">
Modifica
</div>
```